# Can someone check my arithmetic for this beginner C program?

Tags: c, math

I am writing a program in C that calculates this formula:

[image: formula]
<sub>(source: [crewtonramoneshouseofmath.com](http://www.crewtonramoneshouseofmath.com/images/quad_eq.gif))</sub>

here is the line of code (I am just using + instead of the +-):

```
x = ((-1 * b) + (sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)))/(4 * a);
```

I am not getting the correct root. For example if a = 1, b=-2, and c=-2 it SHOULD be 2.73. Instead I am getting 1.37.

Been staring at the code and I don't see the mistake. Can someone point it out for me?

Comment: For reference, `pow(x, 2)` is simpler as `x * x`.  `pow` is better for when you have large or non-integer exponents.

Comment: `-1 * b` can also be stated more simply as `-b` (unary minus operator)

Comment: There can be numerical issues when the numerator and denominator both tend to zero, leading to [catastrophic cancellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). See the *floating point implementation* on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) for a better formula.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`x = (...) / (4 * a)`

Shouldn't this be `2 * a`?

Comment: @Petefic If that was the problem, then you surely just forgot to accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting that 1.37 (what you're getting) is about half of 2.73 (what you want) and, lo and behold, there it is in your denominator, dividing by `4a` instead of `2a`.

Personally, I would write that expression as:

```
x = (-b + sqrt (b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
```

since it more closely matches the equation you're trying to duplicate (the `-1 * b` is better expressed as `-b`) and I find calling `pow` to get a simple square to be unnecessary where `b * b` does the same job without a function call.

Answer (score 0):

x1 = ((-1 * bcoeff) + (sqrt(pow(bcoeff, 2) - 4 * acoeff * ccoeff)))/(**2** * acoeff);

Answer (score 0):

Check yourself here:  `.../(4 * acoeff)`

Answer (score 0):

While this question has already been answered and your error pointed out. I would just like to mention that breaking the problem down into more lines would increase its readability and potentially reduce mistakes made.

```
float den = 2 * a;
float num1 = (-1 * b);
float num2 = pow(b ,2) - (4 * a * c);
float x = (num1 + sqrt(num2))/ den;
```